# How to verify that $U\oplus W$ is a direct sum

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose
$U = \{(x, y, 0)\in F^3: x, y \in F \}$ and $W = \{(0, 0, z) \in F^3:z \in F\}$.
Then $F^3 = U\oplus W$. But why?
$U + W = \{(x, y, z)\in F^3:x, y, z\in F\}$. But can't I express the sum using $U' = \{(x, 0, 0)\in F^3:x \in F\}$ and $W' = \{(0, y, z) \in F^3: y, z \in F\}$ ? I mean, I have no idea why $U\oplus W$ can be expressed in only one way.

Comment: $U+W$ being direct **does not** mean the *vector space* cannot be written as $U'+W'$ with different subspaces $U'$ and $W'$. It means every *individual vector* $v\in V$ is uniquely expressible as $u+w$ with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$. Now, if $(x,y,z)=(?,?,0)+(0,0,?)$, you automatically know what all of the $?$s are, and they are *uniquely* determined from $(x,y,z)$, so that's that.

Comment: I struggle to understand your confusion. What $F^3 = U\oplus W$ means, is that given any vector $v \in F^3$, it can be uniquely written as the sum of a vector $u \in U$, and a vector $w \in W$. So, you need to show that any element  can be written as a sum of vectors from $U$ and $W$, and then show that the sum must be unique. Are you unable to say why the uniqueness comes about, or are you having problems with this definition?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I was thinking this is not unique. So I believe I am having trouble understanding the definition.

Comment: If $(x,y,z)=u+w$ with $u\in U,w\in W$ then the only possibility is $u=(x,y,0)$ and $w=(0,0,z)$. Don't you agree?

Comment: @user214969 +1 for having clarified your problem, because it makes things a whole lot easier.

Comment: Analogy: We have $24 = 8 \times 3$. If we number the entries of an $8 \times 3$ matrix then every element of $1,2,\dots,24$ corresponds to a unique row in $1,2,\dots,8$ and a unique column in $1,2,3$. Well, but also $24 = 4 \times 6$; each of the $24$ entries in a $4 \times 6$ matrix corresponds to a unique row (out of $4$) and unique column (out of $6$). And then there is $24 = 12 \times 2$, and....

Answer (score 1):

When we say that $V = U\oplus W$, this means that every element of $V$ can be uniquely written as a sum of elements from $U$ and $W$. **What it does not mean, is that $U$ and $W$ are unique subspaces that sum to $V$. The uniqueness is in the elements of $U$ and $W$, not in $U$ and $W$ themselves. In fact, in most situations, you will have many $U_i$ and $W_i$ such that $U_i \oplus W_i = V$** So, you are only trying to show that the summation is unique here, not that $U,W$ are unique in any sense. As with your example above, they definitely are not unique.

See, when you are trying to show uniqueness of summation, what do you essentially need to show? That if there are two ways of writing the sum, then these ways must be the same.

> That is, for $v \in F^3$, you must prove that if $v = u_1 + w_1$ and $v = u_2+w_2$, where $u_1,u_2 \in U$ and $w_1,w_2 \in W$, then it is true that $u_1=u_2$, and $w_1 = w_2$.

So starting from the above, we basically get $u_1 + w_1 = u_2 + w_2$, since both are equal to $v$. Since $u_1,u_2 \in U$, we know how they look. That is, $u_1 = (x_{u_1},y_{u_1},0)$, and $u_2 = (x_{u_2},y_{u_2},0)$ for some elements $x_{u_1},x_{u_2},y_{u_1},y_{u_2} \in F$. Similarly, since $w_1,w_2 \in W$, we get that $w_1 = (0,0,z_{w_1}),w_{2} = (0,0,z_{w_2})$ for some elements $z_{w_1},z_{w_2} \in F$.

Now performing vector addition, we get $u_1 + w_1 = (x_{u_1},y_{u_1},z_{w_1})$, and $u_2  + w_2 = (x_{u_2},y_{u_2},z_{w_2})$.

Now, we are saying that the two vectors above are equal. When does this happen? Only when all their components are equal. That is, above, we must have the first components , which are $x_{u_1}$ and $x_{u_2}$, must be equal. Similarly, $y_{u_1} = y_{u_2},z_{w_1}=z_{w_2}$. From here, it's easy to see that $u_1=u_2,w_1=w_2$. So $V$ is a direct sum of $U$ and $W$.

It's similarly shown that for the $U'$ and $W'$ that you have written above, it is true that $U'\oplus W =V$. So, to reiterate, the subspaces that direct sum to $V$ are in no way unique. It is their elements which are key to the uniqueness element of the direct sum.

You will still have doubts, and that's good, it can only help your understanding of the subject. Do ask, of course.